# Live Connect APIs deprecated?

Tags: live-sdk, microsoft-live-connect

For our website we have an option to login with your Microsoft ID. This website uses the Live Connect APIs for authentication and retrieving identity information. We use the following API urls: https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf and https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me.

Lately I stumbled on this documentation page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx which states that the Live Connect APIs are deprecated, and the Outlook REST APIs should be used instead. I can't find more information about this, but what I see is that when I go to outlook.com in a browser, I'm still redirected to login.live.com. So Microsoft itself is still using the Live APIs? And the documentation about the Outlook REST APIs shows the use of login.microsoftonline.com. AFAIK, this API only works for Office 365 accounts, and not with normal Microsoft accounts.

So my question is: are the Live Connect APIs (including the login functionality) really deprecated? And if so: which API should be used to login with normal Microsoft accounts, and when will the Live Connect APIs go offline?

Any insight or further documentation is appreciated.

Regards,

Joost

Comment: 5 months on and the situation is no clearer. Isn't there someone with MS credentials who can clear up this confusion?